# Twilio mobile number verification - VerificationCheck was not found php

Tags: twilio, laravel-7

I want to integrate Twilio for mobile number verification during registration on my web portal.

I sent an OTP to my mobile number successfully but when I'm entering the OTP to verify field then it though an error that is "[HTTP 404] Unable to create record" and "VerificationCheck was not found";

I checked that "VerificationCheck was not found", this error comes due to invalid parameters but the parameters are well formatted as in Twilio Docs.

Please help me out.

Comment: Update - When I enter the right OTP then it works fine but when I enter wrong OTP then above message comes.